# If a creature equipped with assault suit changes controllers, can that creature attack me?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing a game of commander with a friend, and I was wondering if I were to attach [Assault Suit](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Assault%20Suit) to [Evil Eye of Orms-by-Gore](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Evil%20Eye%20of%20Orms-by-Gore). Then transfer the evil eye to him would the equipment fall off? Would he gain control of it's effects? Or would it not be able to attack me?

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any restrictions on equipment controlled by one player being on a creature controlled by another player. The restriction is only on the equip ability itself: "equip" means "put this equipment on a creature you control". You can't use the equip ability to put equipment on another player's creature.

> The equip ability can target only a creature you control. It's okay if Equipment gets onto a creature your opponent controls (such as via your opponent playing Confiscate on your equipped creature), but you can't do this using the equip ability. Also, you can play the ability only any time you could play a sorcery.

[https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/rules-equipment-2003-09-02#:~:text=The%20equip%20ability%20can%20target,you%20could%20play%20a%20sorcery](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/rules-equipment-2003-09-02#:%7E:text=The%20equip%20ability%20can%20target,you%20could%20play%20a%20sorcery).

Also, the control of a permanent is separate from the control of any permanent it may be attached to. So your opponent gaining control of Evil Eye of Orms-by-Gore doesn't affect control of Assault Suit and "you" on Assault Suit still refers to you, so they can't attack you.